# Which data type should be used for storing an integer as large as 10^9 in an array?

Tags: c

I have to code for a problem wherein I have to find the frequency of minimum integer among all the integers scanned. I have declared the array to be of type `size_t` which on my machine has sizeof 8 bytes, I also tried with data type `unsigned long`, still I am getting runtime error on final submission on hackerearth of my code.

I have checked and verified that there is no issue with the code since 3 test cases have passed on given input but it is failing for remaining test cases, so issue with the data type used for storing the number.

Please guide me with the proper data type I should use. Problem is mentioned on below link:

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-lucky-minimum-3/

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
size_t a[100001]={0};
int main()
{
    int test_no,i;

    scanf(" %d",&test_no);
    for(i=0;i<test_no;i++)
    {
        int j,n ;
        size_t x,min;
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf(" %zu",&x);
            a[x]++;
            if(j==0)
            {
                min=x;
            }
            if(x<=min)
            {
                min=x;
            }
        }
        if(a[min]%2==0 && a[min]!=0) //In case if every integer occurs only once so all entries of count will be 0 , so he'll be unlucky 
        {
            printf("Unlucky \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Lucky \n") ;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regular 4-byte `int`s should be okay for your problem. Your problem is that you store the occurrence of the number `x` in `a[x]`, but according to the link, each `x` (or each Aᵢ, as they put it) can be as big as 10⁹, but your array has the dimension 10⁵. (Hint: You don't need an array here, because you only need to keep track of the occurrences of the minium element.)

Comment: You don't clear `a` between test cases, that seems scary.

Comment: Why is `a` global?

Comment: Sort the array, then increment until the first number no more appears.

Comment: "thwre's no issue with the code" "it is failing for remaining test cases". These two statements contradict each other. Please choose one and invert the other.

Comment: @MOehm , How can it be done without array since during scanning the minimum element can be found but when we have to count the frequency of minimum element then we need to store it somewhere otherwise how will we confirm what was the last seen frequency of element ,say for instance .

Comment: @radha: You only need one count, that of the minimum element. At each step you know what the minimum so far is and how often it has occurred. When you find a new minimum, reset the count to zero. At the end you know what the actual minimum is and how often it has occurred. [Voilà](https://ideone.com/r26f6F).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long long` is at least a 64 bit signed type, and more than capable of storing a number of that magnitude.

Modern C compilers (C99 onwards) are required to support it.

(By the way, you don't need to retain all the numbers in an array in order to compute the minimum or maximum - rather you can store the currently attained extremes.)

Comment: @AndreKampling: Interesting link but note an important divergence from C++14: a `signed char` *must* be 2's complement, as must a `char` if it's signed.

Comment: @Bathsheba Did you program any system which is not 2 complement?

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Yup. Plenty of cash registers use signed magnitude. Many moons ago though.

Comment: Discreet electronics ones? But they were not programmed in C. Or maybe one of those: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8V9C.jpg

Comment: @PeterJ_01: That's wonderful. Bonus if you can find a pre-1971 English one (pounds, shillings, pence).

Comment: @Bathsheba not 2.complement may be completelly ignored nowadays as there are no any (except some back compatible with the computers from '60s, ot 70s - but people who do program them do not get their knowledge from SO). So please stop writing anout not 2scomplement as for the SO users they do not exist anymore

Comment: With respect, I'll stop writing about them only if support is dropped from the relevant standards.